# Location attr not relocating on ipad or iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few location attrs on my website for a few dynamic drop downs and clickable divs. While testing I saw that they are not working on any ipads or iphones. Is there a reason for this?

They look like this

```
$('.storyClick').click(function () {
    var context = $(this).closest('.storyClick'),
        story_id = context.find('.story_id').val();
    $(location).attr('href', '/chapters/' + story_id)
});
```

The updated code? Sure...

```
$('.storyClick').click(function () {
  var context = $(this).closest('.storyClick'),
  story_id = context.find('.story_id').val();
  location.href = '/chapters/' + story_id;
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? And what doesn’t work exactly?

Comment: I am trying to make some divs clickable and this works on browsers, but not mobile devices like ipads. I would like to make them clickable so they don't have to find a small little link they can be all thumbs like me.

Comment: And what is supposed to happen when you click? What doesn’t "work"?

Comment: it does not go to the new page...I thought it was obvious with a location that it's supposed to be a link.

Comment: What if you do `window.location.href = '/chapters/' + story_id`?

Comment: It's still doing the same, works on the computer, but not on mobile.

Comment: Maybe replacing .click(...) with .on('click touch', ...) - http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: I just gave the on touch and it didn't work, thats what I originally had, I was just giving the click a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you making a jQuery object out of that?

```
location.href = '/chapters/' + story_id;
```

DOM nodes are the only things that should be wrapped in a jQuery object. (Well, ideally, *nothing* would be, but here we are.)

And you apparently need to handle two events using `.on('click touchstart', …)`, because it’s not a link.

Comment: Maybe because the `href` attribute behavior is inconsistent between browsers, and jQuery normalizes that. But in general, I agree.

Comment: @David: Er, reference?

Comment: @zazvorniki: Can you show your entire updated code? And is it just doing nothing, or...? Does it work anywhere else?

Comment: And you appear to be making a link, which begs the question: why is it not a link?

Comment: @zazvorniki: Any other variables named `location`? Try `window.location.href`.

Comment: because it's a clickable div, I cannot wrap a link around it. And I am also using the same logic for some clickable drop downs.

Comment: no, i do not and I just tried that and it is reacting the same. Works on a computer, but not on mobile.

Comment: @minitech F.ex I believe for `href="/home"`, `node.href` returns the full URL, whereas standard browsers return the relative.

Comment: @David: This is the `window.location` object, I’m assuming.

Comment: @zazvorniki: Okay, one last thing to try – `window.location = '/chapters/' + story_id;`. Also what Blazemonger said.

Comment: @minitech Sorry, I mean the other way around. Try comparing `$('#hlogo a').attr('href');` with `document.getElementById('hlogo').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href` in the console...

Comment: @David: Okay, but `window.location` is not an element.

Comment: @minitech ah I see, the OP was referring to the `window.location` object. My bad...

Comment: @David I don't think I understand what you're saying... what is hLogo and why would I use document.getElementById when I'm using jquery?

Comment: @zazvorniki: Try `touchstart` then? And `window.location = '/chapters/' + story_id;`? I don’t really know where to go from there; maybe the Mobile Safari “debug tools” can give you some hints.

Comment: on touchstart? it doesn't work in the browser anymore if I change it to that.

Comment: @zazvorniki: No, both. `.on('click touchstart', …)`.

Comment: That worked wonders! Thank you! If you put it as an answer, I'll check it! :)